# How can I check how many lines my command for searching processes printed?

Tags: powershell

I have following command, where I can find processes by their name:

```
Get-Process | where {$_.ProcessName -eq "<pName>"}
```

This delivers either:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
202      12        5072       7732       0,03    2740   1 <pName>
```

or no output (or more processes than one).
My Question is how I can determine, which case happened.

I also tried to put the command into  a variable and print `echo $result.ExitCode` and something like that, but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Why not let Get-Process do the filtering? `(ps "<pName>").Count`

Comment: @LotPings What would be the full command for this? I don't fully understand what you meant.

Comment: `ps` is an alias for `Get-Process` and accepts the process name as parameter at position 0. Enclosing in parentheses ().PropertyName is equivalent to appending `|Select-Object -Expandproperty PropertyName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Get-Process` cmdlet returns an array of objects. To figure out how many objects there are in the returned collection (and thus how many lines will be printed), just do:

```
$processes = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -eq "<pName>"}
$processes.Count
```